# javascript function calling with timer not working properly

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

i have write this code for perform simple action but not working at all

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 10;

    function add() {
        window.setInterval(a2, 10000);

            alert(a);

    }
    function a2() {

        a = a + 2;
    }


</script>
```

this alert in only returning value 10 only one time.
how to achieve this working through timing and looping?

Answer (score 2):

If you want more alerts, you need to put `alert()` in the timed function itself. Execution won't return to `add()` from `a2()`.

```
function a2() {
    a = a + 2;
    alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your alert instruction is out of the interval, try the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 10;

    function add() {
        window.setInterval(a2, 10000);
   }
   function a2() {
        a = a + 2;
        alert(a);
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
  var a = 10;

  window.setInterval(add, 1000);

  function add() {
      alert(a);
      a = a + 2;
  }
```